# Convert multiple json files in multiple parquet files

Tags: pyspark

I want to convert multiple json files into multiple parquet files using pyspark. I have 10 different json files in path/to/ folder  with different schemas and I want to make 10 parquet files in the same folder. I am capable converting 1 json file to 1 parquet but don't know how to do with 10 json files dynamically.

Here is the code to convert 1 json file to parquet. But how do I do for 10 json files with one dataframe that produce 10 parquet files

**Initialize a PySpark session**

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("JSON to Parquet Conversion") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

**Read the JSON file into a PySpark DataFrame**

```py
json_path = "path/to/file1.json"
df = spark.read.json(json_path)
```

**Write the DataFrame to Parquet format**

```py
parquet_path = "path/to/file1.parquet
df.write.parquet(parquet_path)
```

**Now this is the code that loop all files in a directory and read them all. I have a syntax error at line 2**

```
import os 
Directory = f'abfss://folder_j@{AZ_NM}.dfs.core.windows.net/files_j/all_files'\
for filename in os.listdir(path=f'{Directory}'):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.join(path=f'{Directory}', filename)) as f:
            print(f.read())
```

```
-----------------------------------------
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_17101/446793651.py", line 2
    for filename in os.listdir(path=f'{Directory}'):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

##Could you please tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: why not just read from the file folder, without specifying the file name?

Comment: I tried that but it combined the data into one dataset and write the result into one big file. I dont want that. I want each json file to be converted to (ie: file1.parquet, file2.parquet, ...file10.parquet)

Comment: Ah - then perhaps a foreach against the directory list? You can start there, try it, and then update your question with specific issues...

Comment: Thank you Dave! That is exactly where I am stuck. I dont know  how to do with a loop. If you could please   help me with that I would appreciate

Comment: import os 
Directory = f'abfss://folder_j@{AZ_NM}.dfs.core.windows.net/files_j/all_files'\
for filename in os.listdir(path=f'{Directory}'):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(os.join(path=f'{Directory}', filename)) as f:
            print(f.read()) 
-----------------------------------------
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_17101/446793651.py", line 2
    for filename in os.listdir(path=f'{Directory}'):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax